# How to place 2 logos on top of each other (overlaying) in center of a fixed header ... to prepare for animation effect on scroll

Tags: html, css

There are similar questions here but I can't find a solution that will work for me.  I'm new at web building so it took quite a lot of effort to finally get my header fixed and designed the way I need it to be.  Now I'm working on doing some animation.  I would like to transition to a different logo when the user scrolls down.

To be more clear: Logo 1 is lying on top of logo 2 and is the only logo that is visible. Upon the user scrolling down, the top logo will fade away exposing the 2nd logo beneath.  To my understanding I need to have both logos centered and positioned correctly ... with one on top of (overlaying) the other.  It seems this could be done with a `position: absolute` container and then placing the logos with `position: relative`. However, doing this completely destroys my `nav` and I don't have the knowledge to correct it. I've also tried using `z-index` without success. I would appreciate help in figuring this out. Thank you in advance.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  min-height: 100%;
}

header {
  height: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  /* border-bottom: 15px solid rgb(197, 179, 55) */
}

#nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 180px;

}

.lg_logo {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.sm_logo {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

#nav_left {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

#nav_right {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

a {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); */
  color: rgb(96, 96, 96);
  font-family: Tenar Sans;
  font-size: .85em;
  margin: 0 1.4em;
  height: 20px; /* need this to correct issue with hover effect */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="nav">
      <div id="nav_left">
          <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
          <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
          <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
      </div>
          <a href="index.html" id="logo" class="lg_logo"><img src="images/logo_6_small.png" alt="Claire Crawford"
                  id="logo_Claire" /></a>
          <a href="index.html" id="logo" class="sm_logo"><img src="images/logo_single_black_bird_120_blue_cc.png"
                  alt="Claire Crawford" id="logo_Claire" /></a>
      <div id="nav_right">
          <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
          <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
          <a href="contact.html">GET IN TOUCH</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your updated question you can do this using `jQuery`  `$(window).scroll(function() {})`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 0) {
      $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-scroll");
      $(".logo").show();
    } else {
      $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-scroll");
      $(".logo").hide();
    }
    if (scroll > 10) {
      $(".navbar").addClass("nav-color");
      $(".logo_main").show();
      $(".logo").hide();
    } else {
      $(".navbar").removeClass("nav-color");
      $(".logo_main").hide();
      $(".logo").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  height: 200vh;
}

header {
  height: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  /* border-bottom: 15px solid rgb(197, 179, 55) */
}

#nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 180px;
  background: black;
}

.lg_logo {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.sm_logo {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

#nav_left {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

#nav_right {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

a {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); */
  color: rgb(96, 96, 96);
  font-family: Tenar Sans;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  margin: 0 1.4em;
  height: 20px;
  /* need this to correct issue with hover effect */
}

.navbar-scroll {
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}

.nav-color {
  background-color: white !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0.29, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0.29, 1);
  transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0.29, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInDown 1s alternate ease;
  -moz-animation: fadeInDown 1s alternate ease;
  animation: fadeInDown 1s alternate ease;
  box-shadow: 5px 8.66px 30px 0 rgba(31, 35, 37, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="nav" class="navbar">
    <div id="nav_left">
      <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
      <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
      <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
    </div>
    <a href="index.html" id="logo" class="lg_logo" style="padding: 0px;width:250px text-align:center">
      <img src="logo2" alt="logo2" id="logo_Claire" class="logo_main" style="display:none" />
      <img src="logo1" alt="logo1" id="logo_Claire" class="logo"/>
    </a>
    <div id="nav_right">
      <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
      <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="contact.html">GET IN TOUCH</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you but I should have been more clear in my question. I need one logo to be laying on top of the other rather than one sitting above the other.  So the top logo will be the only one that is visible. The logo beneath will be hidden until the scroll effect occurs.  Once the user scrolls down the top logo will fade away as the logo beneath is displayed.

Comment: You can hide one logo by default. Display that one while you scroll and hire the first one. You can do that with jQuery

Comment: @Vienne Updated the answer. See the logo will change when you scroll

Comment: Thank you!  This was very helpful. I have it working now.  Could you help me to make the first logo fade out as the second one fades in ... rather than the logos changing instantly?

Answer (score 0):

you can place both the images inside the same anchor tag. Position the anchor tag relatively and then set the position of the image tags to absolute. Alternatively, you can add a div and position the div relatively and then set the position of the anchor tags to absolute.

Kindly refer to the below snippet. let me know if this helps

```css
  body {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    min-height: 100%;
  }

  header {
    height: 160px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    /* border-bottom: 15px solid rgb(197, 179, 55) */
  }

  #nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 180px;
  }

  .logo {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    padding: 0 30px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .sm_logo {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    padding: 0 30px;
    margin-top: 12px;
  }

  .log-img__large {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
  }

  .log-img__small {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  #nav_left {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-top: 80px;
  }

  #nav_right {
    flex: 1 0 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-top: 80px;
  }

  a {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); */
    color: rgb(96, 96, 96);
    font-family: Tenar Sans;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    margin: 0 1.4em;
    height: 20px;
    /* need this to correct issue with hover effect */
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="nav">
    <div id="nav_left">
      <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
      <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
      <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a>
    </div>

    <a href="index.html" id="logo" class="logo">
      <img
        src="images/logo_single_black_bird_120_blue_cc.png"
        alt="Claire Crawford"
        id="logo_Claire"
        class="log-img__large"/>
      <img
        src="images/logo_6_small.png"
        alt="Claire Crawford"
        id="logo_Claire"
        class="log-img__small"
    /></a>
    <div id="nav_right">
      <a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
      <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="contact.html">GET IN TOUCH</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```